# :has CSS pseudo class in Nokogiri

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm looking for the pseudoclass `:has` in [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).
It should work just like jQuery's [`has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

For example:

```
<li><h1><a href="dfd">ex1</a></h1><span class="string">sdfsdf</span></li>
<li><h1><a href="dsfsdf">ex2</a></h1><span class="string"></span></li>
<li><h1><a href="sdfd">ex3</a></h1></li>
```

The CSS selector should return only the first link, the one with the not-empty `span.string` sibling.

In jQuery this selector works well:

```
$('li:has(span.string:not(:empty))>h1>a')
```

but not in Nokogiri:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html_source).css('li:has(span.string:not(:empty))>h1>a')
```

`:not` and `:empty` works well, but not `:has`.

---

1. Is there any documentation for CSS selectors in Nokogiri?
2. Maybe someone can write a custom `:has` pseudo class? Here is an [example](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) how to write a `:regexp` selector.
3. Optionally I can use XPath. How do I write XPath for `li:has(span.string:not(:empty))>h1>a`?

Comment: `:has` pseudo is a jQuery extension, so I guess that Nokogiri does not support it because it's not part of any standard.

Comment: OK, so my last 3 questions are suitable

Comment: Given the HTML you provided, `//li[span[@class="string"][count(node()) > 0]]/h1/a` returns you the node with `ex1` content (the very first `a`).

Comment: @MisterJack, nokogiri support `:has` selector but it isn't working properly, look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11760932/1060407). Thanks for xpath example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [problem with Nokogiri's current implementation of `:has()`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/350) is that it creates XPath that requires the contents to be a direct child, not any descendant:

```
puts Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for( "a:has(b)" )
#=> "//a[b]"
#=> Should output "//a[.//b]" to be correct
```

To make this XPath match what jQuery does, you need to allow the `span` to be a descendant element. For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
d = Nokogiri.XML('<r><a/><a><b><c/></b></a></r>')
d.at_css('a:has(b)')    #=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14dd608 name="a" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14dd3e0 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14dd20c name="c">]>]>
d.at_css('a:has(c)')    #=> nil
d.at_xpath('//a[.//c]') #=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14dd608 name="a" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14dd3e0 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14dd20c name="c">]>]>
```

For your specific case, here's the full "broken" XPath:

```
puts Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for( "li:has(span.string:not(:empty)) > h1 > a" )
#=> //li[span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' string ') and not(not(node()))]]/h1/a
```

And here it is fixed:

```
# Adding just the .//
//li[.//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' string ') and not(not(node()))]]/h1/a

# Simplified to assume only one CSS class is present on the span
//li[.//span[@class='string' and not(not(node()))]]/h1/a

# Assuming that `not(:empty)` really meant "Has some text in it"
//li[.//span[@class='string' and text()]]/h1/a

# ..or maybe you really wanted "Has some text anywhere underneath"
//li[.//span[@class='string' and .//text()]]/h1/a

# ..or maybe you really wanted "Has at least one element child"
//li[.//span[@class='string' and *]]/h1/a
```

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri does not have a `:has` selector, here is the documentation on what it *does* do:
http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/#h-2-2

Comment: In your link, are only some examples how to use It, but not nokogiri css selectors documentation.

Comment: This is the most descriptive and explanatory, if you want to see what i mean, take a look at [Nokogiri's Documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/CSS.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution that maybe will be useful for someone.

Custom pseudoclass `:custom_has`:

```
class MyCustomSelectors
  def custom_has node_set, selector
      node_set.find_all { |node| node.css(selector).present? }
  end
end

#usage:
doc.css('li:custom_has(span.string:not(:empty))>h1>a',MyCustomSelectors.new)
```

Why did I declar `:custom_has` not just `:has`? Because it's already declared.
In the Nokogiri repo are [tests](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/test/css/test_parser.rb#L65) for the `:has` selector, but they are not working. I [reported this issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/739) to the author.

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri allows for chaining `.css()` and `.xpath()` calls on the same object. So any time you feel like using `:has`, just end the current `.css()` call and add `.xpath(..)` (the parent selector). You can even resume your selection with another `.css()` call starting where your `xpath()` left off!

**Example:**

Here's some HTML from wikipedia:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">
        Origin
    </th>
    <td>
        <a href="/wiki/Edinburgh" title="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Scotland" title="Scotland">Scotland</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">
        <a href="/wiki/Music_genre" title="Music genre">Genres</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <a href="/wiki/Electronica" title="Electronica">Electronica</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Intelligent_dance_music" title="Intelligent dance music">IDM</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Ambient_music" title="Ambient music">ambient</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Downtempo" title="Downtempo">downtempo</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Trip_hop" title="Trip hop">trip hop</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;">
        <a href="/wiki/Record_label" title="Record label">Labels</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <a href="/wiki/Warp_(record_label)" title="Warp (record label)">Warp</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Skam_Records" title="Skam Records">Skam</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Music70" title="Music70">Music70</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Say you want to select all of the `<a>` elements inside of the first `<td>` that comes after the `<th>` containing the link with `href="/Music_genre"`.

```
@artistPage.css("table th > a[href='/wiki/Music_genre']").xpath("..").css("+ td a")
```

This will return all of the `<a>`'s for each genre listing.

Now for good measure, let's grab the inner text of all those `<a>`'s and put them in an array.

```
@genreLinks = @artistPage.css("table th > a[href='/wiki/Music_genre']").xpath("..").css("+ td a")
@genres = []
@genreLinks.each do |genreLink|
  @genres.push(genreLink.text)
end
```